# Do baggage cart management units at Toronto Pearson International Airport accept bills and return change?

Tags: luggage, toronto, yyz

Luggage carts at Toronto Pearson International Airport [cost 2 Canadian dollars to use](http://www.torontopearson.com/en/faqs/).  According to the airport website, *The baggage cart management units accept credit cards and US currency*.  Do the baggage cart management units accept bills or only coins?  And do they give change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [a picture of the cart dispensers](http://twitpic.com/cmomb4). It says all rights reserved so I'll just link to it. It clearly shows that they take

- coins
- credit cards
- bills

I don't see any indication of change-giving although it's possible that is below the frame of the picture. Next to the coins slot someone has taped up a diagram of what coins are ok and they appear to be Canadian toonies, loonies, and quarters only. The bills appear to take both Canadian and US bills based on the pictures next to the bill slots - the top two have more colour and are probably Canadian $5 and $10 and the bottom three look, from a distance, like they might be US ones - $1, $5, and $10 would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

I can only offer the page from the manufacturer of the [cart management system](http://www.smartecarte.com/cart-management-units)

> - Accept credit cards (PCI-DSS Compliant)
> - Accept cash
> - Give change
> - Display multilingual instructions
> - Offer the option to provide a reward to customers when they return carts

Unfortunately I could not find anyone taking a picture of the CMU at Pearson to verify the capabilities, but I've seen the same system in use at major airports in the US with exactly capabilities you're looking for.

Comment: Does *accept cash* means they accept bills?  In The Netherlands, machines for buying train tickets accept coins, but not bills.  I will only have bills with me.

Comment: The ones in the US definitely do.  Stands to reason that the Canadian do as well.  I don't think that *give change* would imply coins only.

Comment: Seems good.  I'll accept if experience confirms that it's true :)